# Search for keywords and replace them with their abbreviations

Tags: java, regex, replace, contain

I have a String and list of words. I want to search the each word in that string and replace that word with any shortcut like UPDATE DATABASE to UPD DB. 
Below are the list of words I need to look for

ALTER DATABASE, ALTER TABLE,  ALTER VIEW,  CREATE DATABASE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE SCHEMA, CREATE TABLE,  CREATE VIEW,  DELETE FROM, DROP DATABASE, DROP PROCEDURE, DROP TABLE, DROP VIEW, UPDATE DATABASE.

This is my code ===>

```
   if(payloadStr.contains("UPDATE DATABASE")){ 
payloadStr = payloadStr.replace("UPDATE DATABASE","UPD DB"); 
} else if(payloadStr.contains("ALTER DATABASE")) { 
payloadStr = payloadStr.replace("ALTER DATABASE", "ALTR DB"); 
}
```

I used if else if condition but I don't think that is a efficient way to code. Can any one please help me in this issue. I asked my friends about this they told me to use REGEX but I feel regex is complex for me to understand.

below is the answer for my case:

```
String[] words = { "UPDATE DATABASE", "ALTER DATABASE",
                    "ALTER TABLE", "ALTER VIEW", "CREATE DATABASE",
                    "CREATE PROCEDURE", "CREATE SCHEMA", "CREATE TABLE",
                    "CREATE VIEW", "DELETE FROM", "DROP DATABASE",
                    "DROP PROCEDURE", "DROP TABLE", "DROP VIEW" };

            String[] replaceWith = { "UPD DB", "ALTR DB", "ALTR TBL",
                    "ALTR VW", "CRT DB", "CRT PRCR", "CRT SCHM", "CRT TBL",
                    "CRT VW", "DEL FRM", "DRP DB", "DROP PRCR", "DRP TBL",
                    "DRP VW" };

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

                payloadStr = payloadStr.replaceAll(words[i], replaceWith[i]);
                getLogger().debug(
                        "SQL Statement in Message. Message Modified To Avoid Layer-7 Rejection:  "
                                + payloadStr);
            }
```

Comment: _I used if else if condition_ then show us that.

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.* -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: This is my code ===> if(payloadStr.contains("UPDATE DATABASE")){
              payloadStr = payloadStr.replace("UPDATE DATABASE","UPD DB");
           
     } else if(payloadStr.contains("ALTER DATABASE")) {
      payloadStr = payloadStr.replace("ALTER DATABASE", "ALTR DB");
       }

Comment: Thanks to all whoever replied

Comment: @user1771540 Plese edit this commented code into your original post by clicking on  [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16345686/edit). Commented code is not readable. If we get better idea what you want to achieve, then it will be easy for us to help you better.

Comment: @user1771540 I think regex will be of no use in this case. Your current implementation looks good. I think you can avoid multiple `if-else` by passing required parameters to specific method which can handle your situation.

Comment: @Smit I tried with if else if but its working when message contains on anyone of the words. If there are 2 words like UPDATE DATABASE and ALTER DATABASE both in message then its failing.

Comment: @user1771540 Deleted my answer. So posting it as comment. In this case dont use `else` ie Only `if-if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use `replaceAll()`.  Also you could put all of the terms and replacements in an array.

Like so:

```
String text = "ALTER DATABASE, ALTER TABLE, ALTER VIEW, CREATE DATABASE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE SCHEMA, CREATE TABLE";

String[] terms = {ALTER DATABASE, ALTER TABLE, ALTER VIEW, CREATE DATABASE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE SCHEMA, CREATE TABLE};

String[] replaceWith = {"","","","","","",""}; // whatever you replace with

for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++) {
    // may want to account for uppercase/lower case here too
    text = text.replaceAll(terms[i],replaceWith[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. May be I did not explained my question correctly. It not like what you are explaining. I have one message as string in that there can be any of the words which i have mentioned before like update database, alter table and so on. I have to search for that word it may or may not have those words. If any of those words contain in that string I have to replace with any shortcut name for that particular word.

Comment: Understood but the method above would still work.  Check out the documentation for replaceall()  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

I might not have understood your question well but...
The String class in Java offers a "replace" method, use:

```
String newString = myString.replace("stringToReplace", "replacement");
```

Comment: @user1771540 No need for the IFs. The replace will return the actual string if it does not find anything to replace.